# Jquery: add row with set number of columns and set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid-layout

This will probably sound trivial to you but still..

User inputs a name and two numbers, all stored in variables. This is repeated multiple times.

I want to display that data in a 19 columns row, of which 11 columns are size 1, and the other one is size 8 and begins from the first inserted number (and of course ends on the second one. Better explained in this screenshot:

[image: the grid I need]

Most the libraries are "limited" by the standard 12-columns-per-row (I usually work with Bootstrap), which I cannot use because the data actually makes sense only when on the same row. There is no need to worry about extra-small screens, since this will be used only on computers.

Maybe flexbox?

Open to suggestions, of course :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, so, you have tabular data. What's wrong with using a table? Kinda what they're for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create two classes; one that is `1/19`th of the width of the page, and one that is `9/19`ths the width of the page. Then float both elements to the left:

```css
.one {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 19);
}

.eight{
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% / 19) * 8);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="eight">8</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
```

Then in jQuery, if you want to add a new row, just make sure to give it the new class:

```
$("body").append("<div class='eight'>New Data</div>");
```

Keep in mind that if you want to append data with an **offset**, you'll need to add **empty** `<div>` elements that have the `one` class.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox with `calc()` and `flex-basis` you can apply a class to the element you want to be long.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row > div {
  height: 10px;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 19);
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.row > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}
.row > .long {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 19 * 8);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="long"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row row1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="long"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```